# Проблема с версткой макета

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

В приложении будет 4 фрагемента с похожими параметрами. Они все будут отображать информацию как на картинке. Пробовал использовать Table Layout, но макеты выходят большие + он deprecated. Стоит ли писать адаптер и использовать RecyclerView в такой ситуации? Если да то как быть с "Title"?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте вот такой `RecyclerView` https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: @Jarvis_J, не хотел бы использовать либы.

Comment: по религиозным соображениям?

Comment: @Jarvis_J, именно. Стараюсь использовать минимум либ что бы понимать проблематику самому.

Comment: либы тоже нужно уметь искать и использовать) Можете написать свой адаптер, который выставляет титлы. `RecyclerView` оправдан для динамических/больших списков